# How to scale down an image by aspect ratio exactly?

Tags: arithmetic

I have an image that is (just for example, can be any size):

```
599 original width
599 original height
```

and a destination aspect ratio for example (can be any):

```
1:2
```

I want to scale down the image and make it exactly the aspect ratio, a simple multiplication gives only:

```
299.5 x 599
```

while I expect

```
299 x 598
```

How to get the expected result?

Sorry for my bad English, I find it hard for me to describe a mathematics question well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what the class of problems you are working on, but one approach is to divide $599$ by $2$ and round down because you can't have fractional pixels.  That gives the new dimension in that direction as $299$.  Then multiply that by $2$ to get the size in the other direction, giving $598$.  This gives the largest rectangle of proportion $1:2$ that fits in $599 \times 599$

Comment: I couldn't figure out what is "class of problems", sorry for my bad English. But I see your solution, it is simpler than I imagine, thanks! Also I saw my question got downvotes, don't understand why but maybe it's too easy I guess lol

Comment: Your problem had a square aspect ratio to start.  The aspect ratio you wanted had a $1$ in one proportion instead of something like $3:4$  I don't know the range of problems you want to work with, so can't make sure my solution is sufficient for the whole range.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the aspect ratio can be any, I just tried another aspect ratio 2:3, this time it didn't give me the expect result, but I managed to get that by repeating the method twice. It will finally find both dimension integer number by keeping round down and multiplying, right?

Comment: When you have aspect ratio $2:3$ it should work in one step.  You should divide by the larger number and round down, so $599/3=199$.  Your dimensions are then $2\cdot 199=398$ by $3 \cdot 199=597$